# Running 2 asyncio subscriptions

Tags: python, json, websocket, python-asyncio

I am trying to run 2 different codes in a single script. I can get them to work separately, but I'm struggling to make them work together.

The first is:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

msg = \
{
  "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
  "id" : 9929,
  "method" : "public/auth",
  "params" : {
    "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
    "client_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "client_secret" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}

async def call_api(msg):
   async with websockets.connect('wss://testapp.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
       await websocket.send(msg)
       while websocket.open:
           response = await websocket.recv()
           # do something with the response...
           print(response)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))
```

The second is:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

# To subscribe to this channel:
msg = \
    {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "method": "public/subscribe",
     "id": 42,
     "params": {
        "channels": ["ticker.BTC-PERPETUAL.raw"]}
    }

async def call_api(msg):
   async with websockets.connect('wss://testapp.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
       await websocket.send(msg)
       while websocket.open:
           response = await websocket.recv()
           # do something with the notifications...
           print(response)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))
```

I have tried combining them in 1 script like this:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json


# To subscribe to this channel:
msg = \
    {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "method": "public/subscribe",
     "id": 42,
     "params": {
        "channels": ["ticker.BTC-PERPETUAL.raw"]}
    }

msg1 = \
{
  "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
  "id" : 9929,
  "method" : "public/auth",
  "params" : {
    "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
    "client_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "client_secret" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}

async def call_api1():
   async with websockets.connect('wss://testapp.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
       await websocket.send(msg)       
       await websocket.send(msg1)
       while websocket.open:
           response = await websocket.recv()
           # do something with the response...
           print(response)
           #access_token=response['access_token']
           #print(access_token)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api1())
```

How I get an error saying websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 502.

I think I messed up on the last line `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api1())`. Just to note, I have read that I need to make both my subscriptions from the same websocket as the API only allows 1 at a time.

Would appreciate any help as I am still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself by using a separate async def for each message and than using the following instead of the final line:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))
    asyncio.ensure_future(call_api1(json.dumps(msg1)))      
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print('closing loop')
    loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to create separate tasks for both and then schedule the tasks (using `ensure_future` or `create_task`).

Instead of the `loop.run_forever()` you might also do a `loop.run_until_complete` of a coroutine that does asyncio.wait([task1, task2])

For example:

```
import asyncio

async def task1():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("task1: done")

async def task2():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("task2: done")


async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.ensure_future(task1())
    t2 = asyncio.ensure_future(task2())
    await asyncio.wait([t1, t2])


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```